# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus Integration

Tags: calculus

I've been trying to work on this problem for an hour and for some reason I'm apparently not inputting the correct answer. The problem was to find the derivative of $\int_{x^5}^{x^7} (2t-1)^3 dt$ and I used F.T.O.C to get $-(2x^5-1)^3+(2x^7-1)^3$, but it keeps saying it wasn't correct, all I did was separate the problem into 2 bounds from $x^5$ to 0 and 0 to $x^7$ and reversed the $x^5$ to 0 one making it negative like F.T.O.C guides. What am I doing wrong and what is the correct answer?

Comment: Does it really ask you to integrate it, or to find the derivative of it? If integrating, you should find the antiderivative of $(2t-1)^3$ first.

Comment: It actually asks to find the derivative, I'll edit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let us use the fact that $d \left(\int_a^b f(t) dt \right)= f(b)db - f(a) da$ to do 
$$d\int_{x^5}^{x^7}(2t-1)^3\, dt = (2x^7-1)^3 dx^7 -(2x^5-1)^3dx^5 =(2x^7-1)^3 7x^6 \, dx -(2x^5-1)^3 5x^4 \,dx$$ if you divide it out, you get 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{x^5}^{x^7}(2t-1)^3\, dt = 7x^6(2x^7-1)^3   -5x^4(2x^5-1)^3 $$

Comment: wow thank you so much! I didn't realize i forgot to apply the chain rule and multiply by 7x^6 and 5x^4.

Comment: @JustinWong, you are welcome. when you are using leibnitz rule you don't need to do the antiderivative first. for example, $d \int_1^{2x} \sin(t^2) \, dt = \sin(4x^2) \, 2dx$

Answer (score 0):

If $F(t)$ is a primitive of $(2t-1)^3$ (you don't need to compute it), then
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{x^5}^{x^7}(2t-1)^3 dt = \frac{d}{dx} (F(x^7)-F(x^5)) = (2x^7-1)^3 \cdot 7x^6 - (2x^5-1)^3 \cdot 5x^4$$
where the last equality follows from using the chain rule.